# Remove duplicates in BatchDataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am experimenting with Tensorflow and following  https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification.

In the example the raw_train_ds is of type

`<BatchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))>`

When I load the dataset using pandas, I am able to remove the duplicates (and there are 100+ duplicates in the dataset)

But, Is there a way I can remove the duplicates from the raw_train_ds in tensorflow itself?
Also, how can I do a countplot of the positive and negative reviews?